# Is there any API to get the blockIds of a file sequentially given the file Path?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Given a string to indicate the file, for example "filepath", how to get the blockIds?

I know i can construct a Path and than create a FileSystem, but don't know how to proceed to get the blockIds.

Thanks for any reply.

Answer (score 1):

From the command line you can use the fsck command to get a files block list:

```
hadoop@Studio-1555:/opt/hadoop/hadoop-1.0.2/bin$ ./hadoop fsck /hadoop/mapred/system/jobtracker.info -files -blocks
FSCK started by hadoop from /127.0.0.1 for path /hadoop/mapred/system/jobtracker.info at Mon Jul 09 06:57:14 EDT 2012
/hadoop/mapred/system/jobtracker.info 4 bytes, 1 block(s):  OK
0. blk_-9148080207111019586_1001 len=4 repl=1
```

As for programatically, i'm not sure you can do anything more than what the DFSck program does, and perform a query against the FsckServlet and parse out the results. The BlockLocation object returned from FileSystem.getBlockLocations(..) doesn't give you have the block IDs, but i guess they are an internal mechanism to HDFS, and probably not readily exposed to the client.

Comment: Check org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NamenodeFsck.check() for more details. As mentioned by Chris, some of the API might not be public.

Comment: Thanks Chris. Your solution is helpful. As an alternative, I finally find that if I have an instance of DistributedFileSystem, I can query the blockID by getClient. However, for FileSystem, I still have no idea.

Comment: Good to know, you probably can't get block ID directly from FileSystem as each implementation is different (local file system for example has no notion of block IDs)